# OrientDB POJO mapping with embedded objects

Tags: java, orm, orientdb

When using the Object Database of OrientDB, how can I tell the database, that in my POJO the reference to another custom object or to a list of other custom objects should be stored in the embedded way and not with links. It seems that by default, OrientDB tries to store them in separate documents, which is unnecessary in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need mark your embedded list with `javax.persistence.Embedded` annotation

```
@Embedded
List<YourEmbeddedClass> yourobjects;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I was googling for this for quite some time and it turned out to be so simple :)